# 2007 toyota corolla vibration after front wheel damage

Tags: toyota, steering, shaking

Left front wheel curb damage to 2007 toyota corolla causes rotational vibration noise (localized from left front side when driving) and steering wheel shaking. Put new wheel on, same tire (undamaged) mounted and balanced, still had noise and shaking. Rotated wheel front to back swap, did not help. Changed left front hub, hub bearing, inner and outer tie rod ends, no help.Changed CV axle no help; still have the noise and shaking. Car has 194,000 miles on it. Could the strut be damaged or do you think the lower control arm was damaged? Inspected the lower control arm; does not look like it is damaged and have used hands to check tire mounted to hub top and bottom and left or right, no looseness. Any more ideas I need to entertain here?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see you list anything about brake components... Check the brake rotor as they are common sources of steering wheel vibration, even when not damaged.  If you hit a curb then there's a chance the rotor was warped.